# Using one cell array to create another

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I am running an experiment where I have 5 different conditions and participants gives a response from 0-9 on each trial.
As a result of running the experiment I get two cell arrays - one containing the conditions of each trial and one containing the participants response for that trial.
For example this (for 10 trials, 2 for each condition):

```
condition =

 2     1     4     4     2     5     3     1     3     5


ratings =

 4     2     8     7     4     9     5     1     3     8
```

I would like to run a regression and therefore I wish to convert the condition to a value that actually represents the independent variable, which is distance between two images (in pixels).

level 1 = 580 pixels, 2=480, 3=380, 4=280, 5=180

I'm sorry if this is a very obvious question, but how can I easily create a new cell array - 'distance in pixels' - from my 'condition' cell array?
I am very new to MATLAB and programming so sorry if i'm missed out anything important, i will try and edit this question as much as i can in response to suggestions. 
I am running MATLAB with psychtoolbox on windows.

Comment: `B = 680 - condition.*100;` Why are you using cell arrays?

Comment: thank you so much! I'm not entirely sure. I am planning no running a regression, and I was under the impression that I should do that using cell arrays, but I could very well be wrong!

Comment: If you can avoid using cell arrays, then do so.  Besides which, regression is a very **numeric** centric operation, so don't use cell arrays at all.... in fact, NEVER for regression.

Comment: thanks @rayryeng for the advice! I will try and find another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple approaches.

First, you could use the mathematical relation:

```
condition = [2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5];
B = 680 - condition.*100
```

Which returns:

```
B =

   480   580   280   280   480   180   380   580   380   180
```

Second, you could utilize MATLAB's [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to make a lookup table:

```
condition = [2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5];
level = [580, 480, 380, 280, 180];
B2 = level(condition)
```

Which returns:

```
B2 =

   480   580   280   280   480   180   380   580   380   180
```

I've written these without using cell arrays, but you can utilize [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)/[`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) where needed if you must use cell arrays for some reason.